# Can i change style of skip button in video.js with vast plugin?

Tags: reactjs, video.js, vast

i am newbie in video.js and for ads i have integrated vast-plugin, And i wanted to change the style of Skip-ads-button. 
Is there any way to change this button.
Anyhelp will appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the IMA plugin or something else?